# Javascript gets current Controller and Action on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, controller, action

Is there a way javascript knows the current controller and action in rails?

I have this idea to create a hidden container for current controller and controller. But I would like to know if Javascript has a function to know current controller and action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript runs client side and has absolutely no idea what controller or action is, so there cannot be a function you could use to obtain this sort of information.

But you can teach javascript about those concept. I would alter the layout to do sth like (haml assumed):

```
%body{data: {controller: params[:controller], action: params[:action]}}
```

You can then obtain this data using jQuery:

```
controllerName = $('body').data('controller')
actionName = $('body').data('action')
```

Now the only quesstion is, why do you want to do this. Client side is client side and mixing client side logic with server side implementation might be dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't had idea about client nor server side.

Comment: I'm interested on this, In my case, I need to know controller and action in JS, to activate or deactivate `setInterval` on the menu page, to change body background image, is not a good idea?? Thanks

Comment: beautiful answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gem for this purpose, it is called [Paloma](https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma). 
You can create hooks depending on your current controller_name and action_name to run JS code dependent where you are.